# How to create combined chart with dual bar chart and line chart using aChart Engine?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am doing chart application using achart engine in android. I can created bar chart , Line chart , Dual line chart and Combined Chart with single bar chart with line chart . Now i want to create combined chart with dual bar chart and line chart like this....

And tried it . I can't able to create combined chart.
I think i got an error because of this line.

```
  String[] types = new String[] {BarChart.TYPE,LineChart.TYPE};
```

How can i change this? Can any body help me to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.